# Can't make specific intent filter for root activity in my android app

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I want to access only my splash activity using intent filter.

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
            AutoVerify = true,
            Categories = new[] {
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryLauncher,
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
            },
            DataScheme = "https",
            DataHost =myexample.com,
            DataPathPattern = ""
        )]
```

And I want to access to the activity only with this adress (myexample.com), but every other url, for example myexample.com/mobile do the same thing. How should i stop this?  I have seen other questions related to this, but none of them seem to have an answer for me.

Comment: can you describe what you actually want.

Comment: splash activity is startup activity in my application. So i want to access it only with myexample.com url, not with all urls that have my DataHost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `DataHost="myexample.com"` you can open your app by `https://myexample.com/..`.

If you just need "myexample.com". try the following code:

```
 Uri myURI = Intent.Data;
 Uri address1 = Uri.Parse("https://myexample.com/");
 if (myURI == null)
 {
      //....
 }
 else if (myURI.Equals(address1))
 {
     StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
 }
 else
 {
     //do what you want to do
 }
```